# Laravel - Avoiding code duplication in models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have a method for save some files in my models and I don't wanna duplicate it anymore, which is the best way to avoid this code duplication in Laravel?

You can see bellow some examples of the duplication, there it is the Product and the Articles Models, both have the saveFile method.

How can I isolate this code and reuse it?

```
// App/Article.php
class Product extends Model {
    protected static $storageFolders = "public/products";

    public static function saveFile($file, Array $options = []) {
        $filename = "";
        if (isset($options["name"])) {
            $filename .= $options["name"];
        }
        if ($options["unique"]) {
            $filename .= "-" . time();
        }
        $picture_path = "";
        if ($filename) {
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename .= ".$extension";
            $picture_path = $file->storeAs(SELF::$storageFolders, $filename);
        } else {
            $picture_path = $file->store(SELF::$storageFolders);
        }
        $storage_url = Storage::url($picture_path);
        return $storage_url;
    }
}

// App/Article.php
class Article extends Model {
    protected static $storageFolders = "public/articles";

    public static function saveFile($file, Array $options = []) {
        $filename = "";
        if (isset($options["name"])) {
            $filename .= $options["name"];
        }
        if ($options["unique"]) {
            $filename .= "-" . time();
        }
        $picture_path = "";
        if ($filename) {
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename .= ".$extension";
            $picture_path = $file->storeAs(SELF::$storageFolders, $filename);
        } else {
            $picture_path = $file->store(SELF::$storageFolders);
        }
        $storage_url = Storage::url($picture_path);
        return $storage_url;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) allow you to share methods between different classes. If you put that method in a trait and have both classes use it, that should achieve what you want.

For example:

```
trait SavesFiles
{
    public static function saveFile($file, Array $options = []) {
        $filename = "";
        if (isset($options["name"])) {
            $filename .= $options["name"];
        }
        if ($options["unique"]) {
            $filename .= "-" . time();
        }
        $picture_path = "";
        if ($filename) {
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename .= ".$extension";
            $picture_path = $file->storeAs(SELF::$storageFolders, $filename);
        } else {
            $picture_path = $file->store(SELF::$storageFolders);
        }
        $storage_url = Storage::url($picture_path);
        return $storage_url;
    }
}
```

Then, your models could use it as follows:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use SavesFiles;
    ...
}
```

Anything that differs between models, such as the folder, can be defined on the class, eg `public $folder = 'products';`, and then used in the trait, eg `$this->folder`.

Or, you could create an abstract model class with that method and have both models inherit from it. But traits would be my first choice.

Comment: There are some conversions to use traits in laravel? Ex: Some folder, some name pattern, I haven't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @MateusKoppe You can define things like the folder to use as class variables, and have the trait pick them up from the class.

Comment: I got this error: App\Product and App\Traits\StorageTrait define the same property ($storageFolders) in the composition of App\Product. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed

Comment: I want to configure the $storageFolders variable in each model, as if it is extended from another class.

Comment: @MateusKoppe That means you can't define it in the trait. Anything defined in the trait is copied and pasted into the classes using it, so if you remove the definition of that variable from the trait, it should resolve the issue.

Comment: @MateusKoppe Thing to bear in mind is that the way the PHP interpreter handles traits is essentially copying everything in the trait into the class using it, so if method or property names clash you'll have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Service or a Trait. (you never call method from one controller to another controller).

```
    <?php


    namespace App\Services;

    class FileService
    {

        public function saveFile($file, Array $options = []) {
            $filename = "";
            if (isset($options["name"])) {
                $filename .= $options["name"];
            }
            if ($options["unique"]) {
                $filename .= "-" . time();
            }

            $picture_path = "";    

            if ($filename) {
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename .= ".$extension";
                $picture_path = $file->storeAs(SELF::$storageFolders, $filename);
            } else {
                $picture_path = $file->store(SELF::$storageFolders);
            }
            $storage_url = Storage::url($picture_path);

        return $storage_url;
       }
}
```

Then, in every other class, you just initialize it in constructor, and use.

```
// App/Article.php
class Product extends Model {
    protected static $storageFolders = "public/products";  
    protected $fileService;

    public function __construct(FileService $fileService) 
    {
         $this->fileService = $fileService;
    }

    public function saveFile ($file, Array $options = [] ) {
        this->fileService->saveFile($file,$options);
    }
```